# What does the “&” symbol do in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

What does the “&” symbol do?

```
select *
from emp
where ename like '&A%';
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it out with a sample dataset, or check with the documentation for `LIKE` patterns for the RDBMS you're using?

Comment: Put a context where did you see that symbol. At least it could provide a clue on what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't do or mean anything special in SQL string literal.  It is just stands for itself; i.e. the ampersand character.  So `like '&A%'` means a string that starts with '&A'.

Apparently (Joshua's answer), the ampersand can have special meaning in Oracle SQLPlus.  But that isn't SQL.  It is a different language that has SQL syntax embedded in it.

Comment: select *
from emp
where ename like '&A%';

if i enetr this query then it asking to "enter the value of a "...

Comment: @indresh - What are you using to run this query?

Comment: (oracle 10g)oracle sql +

Answer (score 4):

I infer you are using Oracle RDBMS since `EMP.ENAME` is from one of the example schemas from Oracle.  In Oracle the ampersand "&" can be used as a substitution variable in SQL*Plus (client).  See http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables.php#substitution_variables.

99% of the time, you are probably not doing substitution and want a literal ampersand. Such as `INSERT INTO sometable VALUES ('Black & Decker');` So you would disable substitution first in SQL*Plus with `SET DEFINE OFF`.